# How many ways to pick $25$ objects from $5$ types with at most $10$ of any type?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways to pick $25$ objects from $5$ types with at most $10$ of any type?

The answer is: $C(25+5-1,25) - 5C(14+5-1,14) + C(5,2)C(3+5-1,3)$

Where do the numbers in this answer come from? I understand that for $C(25+5-1,25)$ that is $25$ objects + $5$ types - $1$, $25$, but I am not sure where the $14$ and $3$ are coming from.

I know there is a similar question on this website but following their reasoning I got a completely wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion.

Since we can have at most $10$ of any type, we count and subtract the **violations** by pre-picking **eleven** of one or more types.

Thus $14 = 25-11$ and $3 = 25 - 2*11$ for violating the stipulations for one and two types respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Application of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and of [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The first term $\binom{25+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{29}{4}$ is the number
of sums $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}+n_{5}=25$ where the $n_{i}$ are
nonnegative integers.

This includes the possibilities where one of the $n_{i}$ exceeds
$10$, like $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+10=25$.

This is repaired by subtracting $5$ times (once for each $i\in\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} $)
the number of sums $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}=25-10=15$ which is $\binom{15+4-1}{4-1}$.

If this is done then we are on $\binom{29}{4}-5\binom{18}{3}$. But
possibilities like $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+10+10=25$ are then subtracted
twice.

This is repaired by adding $\binom{5}{2}$ (once for each subset of
$\left\{ 1,2,3,4,5\right\} $ that has cardinality $2$) the number
of sums $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}=5$ which is $\binom{5+3-1}{3-1}$

Our final result is: $$\binom{29}{4}-5\binom{18}{3}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{2}$$